# On a generalization of Gronwall's lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

In my master thesis I would like to show a uniqueness result for some evolution PDE and at the end of the proof I should be able to conclude by applying some kind of generalized Gronwall's inequality but I am not sure how to do it properly. Let me be more precise.

Let $w(t,x) = v_1(t,x) - v_2(t,x)$, where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are two solutions with the same initial data $v_1(0, \cdot) = v_2(0, \cdot) = v_0$ defined on $[0,T] \times \Omega$, with $\Omega \subset \mathbb R$, so that $w(0, \cdot) = 0$. Now, after some work, I am able to prove the following inequality
$$\|w(t, \cdot)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \le \int_0^t f(s) \max_{\tau \in [0,s]} \|w(\tau, \cdot)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2ds.$$
for $f$ some positive function in $L^1(0,T)$. Now if I had
$$\|w(t, \cdot)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \le \int_0^t f(s) \|w(s, \cdot)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2ds,$$
then Gronwall's lemma would give me
$$\|w(t, \cdot)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \le 0$$
which concludes uniqueness. However, here I have this $\max_{\tau \in [0,s]}$ that bothers me and I do not see how I could get rid of it to apply the lemma.. Does one of you have any idea how I should do that ? Is there some kind of generalization of Gronwall's lemma I could apply ?

Comment: Should it be $f(s)$ instead of $f(t)$?

Comment: Yes right, my bad!

Comment: introduce $g(s) = \max_{\tau \in [0,s]} \|w(\tau, \cdot)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2$ and notice that the standard Gronwall lemma is applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $ g(t)=\max_{\tau \in [0,t]} \|w(\tau, \cdot)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2$. This function is not decreasing and
$$
g(t)\le g(t)\int_0^t f(s)\,ds.
$$
For $t_0>0$ s.t. $\int_0^{t_0} f(s)\,ds=1/2$ it leads to
$g(t_0)\le \frac12 g(t_0)$ and therefore $g\equiv0$ on $[0,t_0]$. Repeating this argument gives the desired equality on $[0,T]$.

Comment: Sorry but I do not really understand your argument. You denot $g(t) = \max_{\tau \in [0,s]}\|w(\tau, \cdot)\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$, isn't it $g(s)$ rather than $g(t)$ ? I don't see how you get your inequality either

Comment: Yes, fixed $t$. As for the estimate: $g(t)\le \sup_{0\le \tau\le t} \int_0^\tau f(s)g(s)\,ds\le  \sup_{0\le \tau\le t}\int_0^\tau f(s)g(t)\,ds.$

Comment: Ok great, I see, thanks a lot!!!